# Erro ao criar uma PROCEDURE

Tags: oracle, procedure

Estou criando uma procedure para poder inserir dados no em uma tabela no banco de dados, porém esta dando um erro que não consigo identificar:

Comando:

```
begin
   INCLUIR_CLIENTE(1, 'SUPERMERCADO XYZ', '12345', NULL, 150000);
end;
```

Mensagem apresentada:

> ORA-06550: line 2, column 1:
>   PLS-00905: object PLSQL_SCHEMA_CARLOS.INCLUIR_CLIENTE is invalid
>   ORA-06550: line 2, column 1:
>   PL/SQL: Statement ignored

Estrutura da Tabela Cliente:
[Tabela Cliente](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0GdyC.png)

Procedure que estou criando:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE INCLUIR_CLIENTE 
   (p_id in cliente.id%type,
    p_razao_social IN cliente.razao_social%type,
    p_cnpj cliente.cnpj%type ,
    p_segmercado_id IN cliente.segmercado_id%type,
    p_faturamento_previsto IN cliente.faturamento_previsto%type)
IS
    v_categoria cliente.categoria%type;
BEGIN
    IF p_faturamento_previsto < 10000 THEN
            v_categoria := 'PEQUENO';
        ELSIF p_faturamento_previsto < 50000 THEN
            v_categoria := 'MEDIO';
        ELSIF p_faturamento_previsto < 100000 THEN 
            v_categoria := 'MEDIO GRANDE';
        ELSE
            v_categoria := 'GRANDE';
    END IF;  
    INSERT INTO cliente VALUES (p_id, UPPER(p_razao_social), p_cnpj,p_segmercado_id, SYSDATE, p_faturamente_previsao, v_categoria);
    COMMIT;
END;
```

Os campos da tabela estão todos batendo, mas mesmo assim está dando esse erro. Alguém pode me ajudar, uso a plataforma Oracle Apex ?

Comment: já fechei a pergunta anterior

Comment: Compilation failed,line 21 (17:15:53)
PL/SQL: ORA-00984: column not allowed hereCompilation failed,line 21 (17:15:53)
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored

Comment: Consegue colocar na pergunta a estrutura da tabela de cliente?

Comment: Coloquei o link da descrição da pergunta

Answer (score 0):

Pelo menos no ambiente do Oracle apex deves incluir as colunas do insert, como nesse exemplo:

```
INSERT INTO cliente (RAZAO_SOCIAL,  CNPJ,SEGMERCADO,FATURAMENTO_PREVISTO,CATEGORIA) VALUES
(UPPER(p_razao_social), p_cnpj,p_segmercado, p_faturamento_previsto,
v_categoria);
```

Veja que não incluí o id, pois ao criar a tabela fiz com autoincremento, mas isso é de cada solução. 
 O item p_faturamento_previsto está escrito errado em seu insert; p_faturamente_previsao

Verifique a ordem de inclusão da chamada da procedure, como não sei como declarou os tipos nas tabelas, pode ser que a ordem esteja trocada. 
 isso aconteceu comigo até corrigir na sequência correta.
Isso não foi um erro, pois é uma diretiva não obrigatória, mas não colocou a cláusula in, ou in out para o CNPJ. 
A chamada ficou assim:

```
begin    
     INCLUIR_CLIENTE(1, 'SUPERMERCADO ABC', 123645,  'A', 150000 ); 
end;
```

O primeiro argumento da procedure para mim não serve, o id, foi apenas para manter o mesmo modelo que você usou.